# Search over multiple fields

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

I think I don't unterstand django-haystack properly:

I have a data model containing several fields, and I would to have two of them searched:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True, default=None)
    twitter_account = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
```

My search index settings:

```
class UserProfileIndex(SearchIndex):
    text = CharField(document=True, model_attr='user')
    twitter_account = CharField(model_attr='twitter_account')

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return UserProfile.objects.all()
```

But when I perform a search, only the field "username" is searched; "twitter_account" is ignored. When I select the Searchresults via dbshell, the objects contain the correct values for "user" and "twitter_account", but the result page shows a "no results":

```
    {% if query %}
        <h3>Results</h3>

        {% for result in page.object_list %}
            <p>
               <a href="{{ result.object.get_absolute_url }}">{{ result.object.id }}</a>
            </p>
        {% empty %}
            <p>No results</p>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess thats because haystack uses the document field for generic searches unless you define a specific search for other fields like the twitter_account field.

[from haystack documentation](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#creating-searchindexes)

> Every SearchIndex requires there be
>   one (and only one) field with
>   document=True. This indicates to both
>   Haystack and the search engine about
>   which field is the primary field for
>   searching within.

Try specifing the index as follows

```
class UserProfileIndex(SearchIndex):
    text = CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    user = CharField(model_attr='user')
    twitter_account = CharField(model_attr='twitter_account')
```

and create the a file named
search/indexes//userprofile_text.txt

which will contain the following

```
{{ object.user.get_full_name }}
{{ object.twitter_account}}
```

now haystack will search in the contents of this file (where you can add whatever you want) when you don't specify an index filter.