# haystack multiple field search

Tags: python, search, django-haystack, whoosh

Hi i m using haystack with a woosh as search engine:

my model looks as follows

```
class Person(models.Model):
    personid = models.IntegerField(primary_key = True, db_column = 'PID')  
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length = 50, db_column = 'FIRSTNAME')  
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length = 50, db_column = 'LASTNAME') 
    class Meta:
        db_table = '"TEST"."PERSON"'
        managed = False


class TDoc(models.Model):
    tdocid = models.IntegerField(primary_key = True, db_column = 'TDOCID')  
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, db_column = 'PID')
    content = models.TextField(db_column = 'CONTENT', blank = True) 
    filepath = models.TextField(db_column = 'FILEPATH', blank = True) 
    class Meta:
        db_table = '"TEST"."TDOC"'
        managed = False
```

The search_index.py is as follows:

```
class TDocIndex(SearchIndex):

    content = CharField(model_attr = 'content', document = True)
    filepaht = CharField(model_attr = 'filepath')
    person = CharField(model_attr = 'person')

    def get_queryset(self):
        return TDoc.objects.all()

    def prepare_person(self, obj):
        # Store a list of id's for filtering
        return obj.person.lastname

site.register(TDoc, TDocIndex)
```

My problem is i would like to do multiple filed searches like

> content:xxx AND person:SMITH

On haystack it search all of them at once i can't do specific field search.
I suspected that my index is corrupt but:

```
ix = open_dir("/testindex")

searcher = ix.searcher()

mparser = MultifieldParser(["content", "filepath", "person"], schema = ix.schema)
myquery = mparser.parse(content:xxx AND person:SMITH')
results = searcher.search(myquery)
for result in results:
    print result
```

but it works and return's the correct value.
I m using the standard haystack SearchView,search.html from the tutorial

```
(r'^search/', include('haystack.urls')),
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your index you should define one field with `document=True`, which is the document haystack will search on. By convention this field is named `text`. You add extra fields if you plan to do filtering or ordering on their values.

The way to take several fields in account when you perform a search, is to define the document as a template, and set `use_template` on your document field. Your Index would look like:

```
class TDocIndex(SearchIndex):

    text = CharField(document=True, use_template=True)

    #if you plan to filter by person
    personid = IntegerField(model_attr='person__id') 

site.register(TDoc, TDocIndex)
```

And you'd have a search/indexes/tdoc_text.txt template like:

```
{{ object.content }}
{{ object.filepath }}
{{ object.person.lastname }}
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2741778/993769) answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `prepare` method in your index class like this:

```
from apps.main.models import Person
from haystack import indexes


class PersonIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True)
    lastname = indexes.CharField(null=True)

    date_insert = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr="date_insert", indexed=False)
    date_update = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr="date_update", indexed=False)

    def get_model(self):
        return Person

    def get_updated_field(self):
        return "date_update"

    def index_queryset(self, using="default"):
        return self.get_model().objects.all()

    def prepare(self, obj: Person):
        data = super().prepare(obj)

        main_fields = [obj.content, obj.filepath, obj.person.lastname]
        data["text"] = "\n".join(f"{col}" for col in main_fields)
        data["lastname"] = obj.person.lastname.lower()

        return data
```